# Hold on option in VBA Graph plot

Tags: vba, excel

I am usually plotting the x axis data from a range in Column A, and y axis data from a range in y column. These are results of some calculations.

After the graph is plotted, I want to keep the plotted graph (hold on like in MATLAB) and add some further operation on the excel Range in column A. Is there any way to execute this?

In this regard, the chart object is not in the sheet and is added as a chart sheet.

Currently when I do this right now, even if the add the codes to change the operation on column A at the end of my macro (after plotting the desired Graph), still it effects the plotted chart object.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is saving the plot in a jpeg what you want? Otherwise you may have to copy column A to another sheet and use that for reference.

Comment: No I dont want to save the plot in a jpeg. Just wanted kind of "hold on" option i.e. once a plot is executed with certain range,  let that plot be saved in the chart-sheet, even if the range is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the chart and de-link it by changing the data source to the current data values.

```
mySeries.XValues = mySeries.XValues
mySeries.Values = mySeries.Values
mySeries.Name = mySeries.Name
```

Now you'll have a chart frozen in time at those current values.  See [this post](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/DelinkChartData.html) for more details.